# How to use CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction for specific instance

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I can use this code:

```
var OriginalFunction = CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction;
CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction=function(n,x)
{
  OriginalFunction(n, x);
  alert("Called From New function");
}
```

To add a javascript function beside the regular function of he CKeditor toolbar buttons. but i need to be able to add to a specific editor instance. so i tried:

```
var OriginalFunction = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.tools.callFunction;
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.tools.callFunction=function(n,x)
{
  OriginalFunction(n, x);
  alert("Called From New function");
}
```

But then the function i add don't work. is there another way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get an error (not "doesn't work" but a javascript error) because `tools` isn't a member of the editor instance.

You might want to use the [afterCommandExec](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-afterCommandExec) event instead.

Comment: How would i use it? `CKEDITOR.instances.FormLinePreview.afterCommandExec(evt){ alert("Called From New function");}` ?

Comment: No, this is an event so you use it like any other event: instance.on("afterCommandExec", function (evt) {})

Comment: Why doesn't it work when you press on a dropdown list option (for example 24 on the font-size list)?

Comment: Showing the contents of a dropdown list isn't executing any command